# Calculate the length of the parallelogram's diagonals

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors

**Calculate the length of the parallelogram's diagonals.**

[image]

According to my book, $å=|u-z|$, and not $|z+w|$. $|u-z| \neq |z+w|$.

> Q: If I am wrong, why am I wrong and if so, why do you calculate $å$ as $|u-z|$ and not $|z+w|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the origin be $O(0,0)$. Then, it is easy to see that that $OUWZ$ is a parallelogram with $U(4,6) ; W(7,5) ; Z(3,-1)$.

Note that $$OZ = UW = \sqrt{3^2+1^2} = \sqrt{10}\, \text{ and } OU = WZ = \sqrt{4^2+6^2} = \sqrt{52}$$

Also, $$UZ = \sqrt{7^2+1^2} = \sqrt{50}$$

This implies that $UZ$ should be the diagonal, instead of $ZW$, right?

Comment: Hmm... are the diagonals of a parallelogram always equal?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1548490/why-are-the-diagonals-of-a-parallelogram-not-equal

Comment: I think that one diagonal is of length $\sqrt74$, but another is of length $\sqrt50$. In which way, you offered me a new insight in how to view vectors so that was very helpful :).

Comment: @AndreasAlmgren Thanks for correcting the typo. And yes, the diagonals of a parallelogram are not equal, but in the case they are, then it becomes a rectangle, right?